# Is it correct to say "he checked into the airport"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I am sure we can say "**we checked into the hotel**" because we want to use a room/service in the hotel.

We often say "**we checked in at the airport**".

I don't think "**we checked into the airport**" because we don't use any service in the airport.

If we are forced to say "**checked into**", then I think we can say "**he checked into his flight at the airport**". But I am not sure if we can say that.

**Note**: there is a difference between "**check in**" and "**go through customs and passport control**". You check in first before you go through customs and passport control.

**Another note**: we can not say "**he checked out of the airport**" but "**we got out of the airport through customs**"

Is it correct to say "**he checked into the airport**"?

Comment: I assume this is when taking a flight, rather than going to the airport for another reason (e.g. because you work there)?

Comment: I'm not even sure that "checked into the hotel" is correct;  I want to say that it should be "checked in to the hotel".  But I'm not sure what the accepted grammar rules are about this.

Comment: *Is it correct to say "he checked into the airport"?*  No.  The logic in your question is completely valid.

Answer (score 4):

**check into a flight**

Like you said, we don't check into airports at all, we just walk in the front door. Our business is with the airlines, not the airport, so if you want to mention the airline add "*...with the airline*".

If the context is clearly a flight, you can simply say:

**check in**

No need to mention the flight, airline or airport.